# For all the guesses below 11 it shows me the answer instead of letting me try further? (Python, Guess the number)

Tags: python

**Summary:** I've just started learning python and I was trying a program of Guess the no.(Ai How to automate the boring stuff). So I typed the code with my own logic instead of just copying it and it gives me unexpected results. I'm using Python IDE ([www.python.org](http://www.python.org))

**What I'm trying to do:** Guess a no. between 1-20 in 6 tries.

**Problem:**
For all the guesses below the no. '11', it directly gives me the answer instead of letting me attempt further tries. The problem is I've not mentioned anything regarding no. less than 11 or so.

**What I've tried:**

1. The book that I'm reading has a code for the same thing and I've tried checking it with my code and it is the same except for the variables(I mean the logic is correctly written). So ideally it should work. and I'm getting confused as to what is causing the problem.
2. I've tried searching the net for various solutions of code not running as expected for the specific code and didn't find anything to help me.

**Code:**

```
import random
print('I have selected a random no. from 1-20')
print('You have 6 tries to guess the no.')
X=random.randint(1, 20)
for i in range(1,7):
    print('Enter your no.')
    A=int(input())
    if A>X:
        print('The no is smaller than you chose')
    elif A>X:
        print('The no is larger than you chose')
    else:
        break
if A==X:
    print ('Yes, you guessed the right no. in'+''+str(i)+'tries')
else:
    print ('No, my no. was'+' '+str(X))
```

Comment: Take a really close look at the condition of the `elif`, and compare that condition with the one in the `if`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `A>X` on both the `if` and the first `elif` branch. The condition on the `elif` should be `A<X`:

```
if A>X:
    print('The no is smaller than you chose')
elif A<X: # Here!
    print('The no is larger than you chose')
else:
    break
```